# Deserializing Json to Object list

Tags: windows-runtime, json.net

I have the following Json that I am looking to deserialize into a list of TwitterTiles (see below).

JSON:

```
{
    "twitterTile": 
    [
        {
            "hashtag": "#genoa",
            "isPositive": true,
            "dateSearched": "08/05/2013"
        }
    ]
}
```

Class definitions:

```
public class TwitterTile
{
    public string hashtag { get; set; }
    public bool isPositive { get; set; }
    public string dateSearched { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<TwitterTile> twitterTile { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is I can't seem to successfully deserialize this json. I've tried a few methods (below) and it's gotten me nowhere.  All of these methods end up returning a null object.  I'm sort of lost as to why this is happening.  Anyone have any ideas?

```
var des = (RootObject)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data, typeof(RootObject));
RootObject topics = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code looks OK to me.  I ran it and it deserialized fine for me using Json.NET v5.4.11.  The exact program I used is below.  I think the problem may not be the deserialization, but that whatever method you are using to retrieve the JSON in the first place is not working.  Did you verify that you are getting valid JSON back?  If so, then is there something else in your code that could be nulling it out before you try to deserialize it?  What happens when you step through your code in a debugger?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json =
        @"{ 
            ""twitterTile"": 
            [ 
                { 
                    ""hashtag"": ""#genoa"", 
                    ""isPositive"": true, 
                    ""dateSearched"": ""08/05/2013"" 
                } 
            ] 
        }";

        RootObject result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

        foreach(TwitterTile tile in result.twitterTile)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hashtag: " + tile.hashtag);
            Console.WriteLine("isPositive: " + tile.isPositive);
            Console.WriteLine("dateSearched: " + tile.dateSearched);
        }
    }

    public class TwitterTile
    {
        public string hashtag { get; set; }
        public bool isPositive { get; set; }
        public string dateSearched { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<TwitterTile> twitterTile { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
hashtag: #genoa
isPositive: True
dateSearched: 08/05/2013
```

Comment: That actually worked fine, the only thing I needed to change was my RootObjects List id to twitterTile and hey presto it worked. Weird. Thanks for the help !